# How to message or notify guests in an event using Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-canvas

I am trying to make a Facebook app that reads the events of an user (who permits the app to do so), and then shows a list of events. The user then chooses one of the events, and the app automatically sends a custom message or notify via Facebook notifcations to the guests of that event. Can I achieve this at all under the FB Graph API?

I realized that /invitable_friends is no longer supported (unless the app is a Canvas game) - however I am not sure if this will prevent me from doing the above

Comment: No that is not possible. You will not be able to access the emails of the guests

Comment: Is there a possiblity of sending a message or notification to the guests inside Facebook?

Comment: No. Just post in the event instead.